# details of an error in android

Tags: android, eclipse, exception

I'm using eclipse to programe in android. But I have a problem debugging: I can't see the details of an exceptions, errors, anything-happen when the app crash... I can copy the stack trace but it give something like:

```
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException))  
ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, boolean, boolean)line: 3348  
ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(IBinder, boolean, boolean) line: 3305   
ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(IBinder, boolean, boolean, int) line: 3288   
...
```

It doesn't say anything about the crash. I need to see the line where it crash, or some kind of information... I cant know what I am doing bad.

There is anything to see more information? I read people showing android errors with a lot of detail, for example:

```
02-01 15:13:41.316: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3989): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cccc.xxxx/com.cccc.xxxx.ActivityMyScreen}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: contentView required: pkg=com.cccc.xxxx id=3145728 notification=Notification(vibrate=null,sound=null,defaults=0x0)
```

How did he do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Open the LogCat view in eclipse: window/show view/other/android/logcat

Or the DDMS perspective: window/open perspective/other/DDMS

Answer (score 0):

I think you're referring to the logcat output available from the Android ADB. You can check out the official docs on logcat here http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/logcat.html.

This also looks like a good description of general debugging steps within eclipse, which will also show you the logcat window by default if you switch to the Android Debug perspective. http://www.droidnova.com/debugging-in-android-using-eclipse,541.html

Comment: What do you mean by "logcat is not doing anything"? Are you on an emulator or an actual device? Logcat is rather chatty so you should at a minimum see a lot of informational messages going by in the log.